# Unable to connect code from a third-party library

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I try to connect this library, but this error falls in the code. I did not find answers in the forums, what am I doing wrong?

https://github.com/miraan/CalendarDateRangePickerViewController

https://yadi.sk/d/Cze6fOwcrV01tA

```
let dateRangePickerViewController = 
CalendarDateRangePickerViewController(collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
dateRangePickerViewController.delegate = self
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: 
dateRangePickerViewController)
self.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, 
completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we should not have to click multiple links just to understand what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CalendarDateRangePickerViewController](https://github.com/miraan/CalendarDateRangePickerViewController) Has not been updated since 2 years so you need to make some changes to use that library.

Here I have implemented it with Xcode 10.1 and follow the below steps to use it.

First of all add pod to your pod file.

```
pod 'CalendarDateRangePickerViewController'
```

then use `pod install` command.

then select your pod from Targets. Check below image for that.

[image]

then step 3 search for `Swift Language Version` and select `Swift 3` there.

Then go to your class where you want user this library

and add

```
import CalendarDateRangePickerViewController
```

and now your third party library is ready to use and you can add example code will look like:

```
import UIKit
import CalendarDateRangePickerViewController

class ViewController: UIViewController, CalendarDateRangePickerViewControllerDelegate {

    func didTapCancel() {

    }

    func didTapDoneWithDateRange(startDate: Date!, endDate: Date!) {

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dateRangePickerViewController =
            CalendarDateRangePickerViewController(collectionViewLayout:
                UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        dateRangePickerViewController.delegate = self
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:
            dateRangePickerViewController)
        self.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true,
                                           completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=10124789536695145284) is the sample project for more info.

**EDIT:**

But with this whenever you hit `pod install` or `pod update` command in terminal you need to set `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 3` again.

Comment: You don't need to and should never manually modify 3rd party dependencies managed via CocoaPods. You can specify what Swift version to use for each pod in your podfile.

Comment: Yes I agree but I don't think this library is offering that support. But if you know the way please share. I would like to know.

Comment: If you can manually modify the project file without having to modify the code as well, the same can be achieved via the Podfile, since the podfile also modifies the pod's project file. However, if you do it via the podfile, updating the library won't break your changes, which isn't true for manual modification of the library's code/project.